# Bash - move files into numbered folders oneliner

Tags: bash, zsh

I can create multiple numbered folders at once like so:

```
mkdir Season\ {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Is there a way I can run the following commands in a oneliner (without a for loop):

```
mv 01.* Season\ 1
mv 02.* Season\ 2
mv 03.* Season\ 3
mv 04.* Season\ 4
mv 05.* Season\ 5
```

Bonus points if there's a ZSH way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(<1-5>).*' 'Season $(($1))'
```

(remove the `-n` when happy)

Note that it calls one `mv` per file so it would be less efficient than the 5 `mv` commands of your question (unless you do a `zmodload zsh/files` beforehand to get a builtin `mv`).

A `perl`'s `rename` alternative:

```
rename -n '$_="Season $1/$_" if /0*(\d+)/' 0[1-5].*
```

(remove `-n` when happy)

Note that `rename` calls the `rename()` system call, so that only works to move files within the same file system (while `mv` will resort to copy+unlink when moving files across file system boundaries).

With `mmv` (moving across FS boundary is supported, but then note that not all attributes will be preserved and for symlinks a copy of the target file is created):

```
mmv -n '0[0-9].*' 'Season #1/'
```

(remove `-n` when happy)

Comment: Nice. I only ever used `zmv` for renaming files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf,xargs combo:

The printf feeds numbers 1 to 5, one at a time `-n 1`, current number is frozen in `{}` and then passed onto the `sh` on it's commandline. The argument is then used to construct the appropriate `mv` command.

```
printf '%d\n' {1..5} | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'mv "0$1".* "Season $1"' {} {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash solution, while loop goes over all seasons and copies files to appropriate folders.

```
season=0; max_season=5; while (( ((season++)) < ((max_season)) )); do mv 0${season}.* Season\ ${season}; done
```

Comment: I suppose I did specify no `for` loop ;)

Comment: Actually, that's a `zsh` solution. In `bash`, you'd need to quote those parameter expansions unless you can guarantee that code will never be used in contexts where `$IFS` has been modified (and in `bash`, you often need to change `$IFS` as `bash` doesn't have dedicated splitting operators like in `zsh`).

Comment: @mafrosis so I did it using while loop :^)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas my bad, checked where my /bin/sh points to and it's actually dash